# T-SQL how to SUM a text data?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I got a field value `0+6+6+6+0+0+0` data type is varchar. how can I get sum of it.

I have tried to convert to int but I got error.

```
select cast('0+6+6+6+0+0+0' as int)
```

I want output as `18`.

Comment: You need to use a string splitter, and split those values based on the `+`. Since you aren't on 2016, I'd suggest using [this one](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function). Then, you'd simply use `SUM()`.

Comment: Is it really a simple sum or are you looking to perform more complex calculations?   As you know by now SQL Server does not have an Eval() function.  That said, there may be dynamic SQL alternatives.

Comment: I'd go after the database guy with a baseball bat first for storing a + and a number together in the same column to be honest.If anybody wants a +, they can concatenate one. For crying out loud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to perform the calculation on every record in your table.

**Example**

```
Declare @YOurTable table (ToEval varchar(50))
Insert Into @YOurTable values
 ('0+6+6+6+0+0+0')
,('5+6+25')

Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YOurTable A
 Cross Apply (  
                Select Value = sum(Value)
                 From  (
                        Select  Value = B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(ToEval,'+','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)) A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                       ) B1
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ToEval          Value
0+6+6+6+0+0+0   18
5+6+25          36
```

Answer (score 4):

As John states, dynamic sql will do this:

```
declare @x varchar(20) = '0+6+6+6+0+0+0';
exec ('select ' + @x + ' as answer');
```

But i'll guess that you have over-simplified things. And perhaps the bigger question is why you have a formula in a string that you need to compute using tsql.

Comment: Hi @SMor, that's how my data in the database. I will try with your logic see how it will work. Thanks

Comment: Note that this approach is potentially (very) unsafe with respect to SQL Injection. If someone manages to get unchecked texts in there, you may end up in the evening news.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL server 2016 and above you could use following

```
        DECLARE @NumbersString VARCHAR(1000) = '0+6+6+6+0+0+0'

        SELECT  SUM(cast(value as int)) 
        FROM    string_split(@NumbersString,'+')
```

if you are using MS Sql version below 2016

```
        DECLARE @NumbersString VARCHAR(MAX) = '0+6+6+6+0+0+0'

        SELECT SUM(cast(Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') as int)) DATA
        FROM
        (
            SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@NumbersString, '+', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
        ) AS A
        CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a);
```

Comment: Hi @indika ranaweera, My Server version is 2012. I will try your code. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you will have such incident repeatedly, you can create a function that will split the numbers from the delimited text. Then you can apply SUM casting the column to integer. This is how it works:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[splittext] 
   (@delimiter VARCHAR(5), 
      @text      VARCHAR(MAX)
   ) 
   RETURNS @values table
      (Id   SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1), 
       delimitedvalue VARCHAR(MAX) 
      ) 
AS 
   BEGIN

      DECLARE @len INT

      WHILE LEN(@text) > 0 
         BEGIN 

            SELECT @len = (CASE CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @text) WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@text) 
            ELSE (CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @text) -1)END) 

            INSERT INTO @values 
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@text, 1, @len )

            SELECT @text = (CASE (LEN( @text )- @len) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE RIGHT(@text, LEN(@text) - @len - 1) END) 
         END

      RETURN 

   END
```

Then to get the SUM:

```
SELECT  SUM(CAST(delimitedvalue AS INT)) FROM dbo.[splittext] ('+', '0+6+6+6+0+0+0')
```

Comment: Just a note, this would have terrible performance over any decently sized dataset.

Comment: As splitters go this is about the worst possible way for performance. See the link that @scsimon posted on the OP or [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) for some other options.

Comment: Got you! I was focused into solving the problem and another work around; but should consider performance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Simply go for below code:

```
 SELECT SUM(CAST(VALUE AS INT)) FROM STRING_SPLIT('0+6+6+6+0+0+0','+')
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in **no way re-usable** but by providing a re-usable solution I think I will be encouraging bad data.

This will do what you want, for now.

```
DECLARE @fullString VARCHAR (20) = '0+6+6+6+0+0+0'

DECLARE @firstNo INT = CAST(SUBSTRING(@fullString,3,1) AS INT)
DECLARE @secondNo INT = CAST(SUBSTRING(@fullString,5,1) AS INT)
DECLARE @thirdNo INT = CAST(SUBSTRING(@fullString,7,1) AS INT)

SELECT
    @firstNo + @secondNo + @thirdNo AS 'Total'
```

Your number isn't big, you can easily cast three numbers and add them. Ideally, no value such as `'0+6+6+6+0+0+0'` should exist in one column. Judging by what you want to do, I imagine that each number represents something different so each number should be stored as such. I'd focus on solving the actual problem and fixing the data. Even if you find a way to work with this data now, you'll shoot yourself in the foot sooner or later.